# How do I stop JavaScript running on pages that do not contain elements in query?

Tags: javascript, joomla

I have some very simple JavaScript in a Joomla 4x development website to add a class to the first element it finds containing specific classes. It works perfectly on the page that contains those elements, but on any other page I get the message "Uncaught TypeError: Years is null".
I'm using `querySelector` so that the script will stop at the first instance of the CSS class, which is what I want.

This is my code:

```
      if (document.querySelectorAll('.group-toggle')) {
      let Years = document.querySelector('.year.toggle-form');
      Years.classList.add('form-opened');
      }
```

I have tried the following:

```
function openYears() {
    if (document.querySelectorAll('.group-toggle')) {
    let Years = document.querySelector('.year.toggle-form');
    Years.classList.add('form-opened');
    }
}
```

and also

```
if (document.querySelector('.group-toggle')) {
let Years = document.querySelector('.year.toggle-form');
      function openYears(){
        let Years = document.querySelector('.year.toggle-form');
        if (document.querySelector('.group-toggle')) {
        Years.classList.add('form-opened');
        }
    }
}
```

but although the error message goes away, the script no longer works.

I'm sure it's blindingly obvious to you, but not to me.

TIA

Comment: It would help if we could see the actual html markup and the element that you are targeting.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no matching element, the result of `querySelectorAll` will be an empty array. An empty array is also truthy however (`if ([]) alert('hi')` will show the alert).

You could either check the array's *length* instead (`if (document.querySelectorAll(...).length)` - zero isn't truthy) or replace `querySelectorAll` with plain `querySelector`, because the latter looks for just the first matching element and returns it (not an array of elements), and it will return `null` (which is *not* truthy) if no such element could be found.

Comment: Removing the 'All' from my first code did the trick. Thank you.